# Cloning a git repo in AWS Instance? I get the error : Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github

This is my first time setting up a LAMP stack in AWS (Amazon Web Services). I have changed my security settings of my instance to include ICMP traffic (anyone), HTTP TCP port 80 (anyone), ICMP echo reply (anyone). All of these security settings were set up for inbound.

When I tried to do it, I get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user-name/example.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Did I miss a critical step in setting up my aws instance?

I am completely new at this. I followed the instructions in Amazon's documentation.

Any suggestions as to how I can troubleshoot this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: HTTPS is not port 80. It's port 443.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good catch. I added HTTPS port 443 now in my inbound connections (anywhere). I refreshed the server, logged out, logged back in. I tried again and I got: ` fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cat-turner/newsmaps.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out `

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem once I added the following to my outbound connection for my group security setting:

```
Type: All traffic
Protocol: All
ip: 0.0.0.0/0
```

This also fixed my sudo yum install issues too.

Comment: Yah I am not sure why it wasn't there. Hey, free learning lesson there.

Comment: That's a bit of a hack. Defeats the purpose of using security group.